# How to allow sharepoint users to comment on blogs as anonymous?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, blog, anonymous-authentication

I have blog create for my staff in sharepoint. The staff are all users. But when they comment on some posts, they want to comment as anonymous. Is there a way for it without an external solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/how-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-comment-on-a-sharepoint-2010-blog.aspx) Basically you have to break inheritance on the Comments library and allow anonymous users to add items.

Comment: It's also important to remove the group/users as contributors on that list otherwise they'll automatically be logged into it.

Answer (score 0):

There's and Microsoft custom web part for that! With an overwhelming request to providing users the capability to display blog post anonymously, Microsoft created a web part you can download on CodePlex that should meet your needs.

Check it out!

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=719
http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/6282

Comment: it didnt work. I tried with my sharepoint site